# how to count in one table and get record from another table

Tags: sql

I need help with the following query
i have 2 tables first one location with primary key no_location and one of the entry no_membre and second table membre with no_membre as primary key and entries prenom_membre and nom_membre
I need to know how to get prenom_membre and nom_membre of members that did more than 25 location.
thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add the SQL code that you used to set up and load the tables along with what you tried in order to get this to work?  Review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use HAVING clause to determine the result set to have more than 25 locations.

```
   SELECT prenom_membre,
           nom_membre,
           COUNT(no_location)
      FROM membre m
      JOIN location l
        ON m.no_membre = l.no_membre
     GROUP BY prenom_membre,
              nom_membre
    HAVING COUNT(no_location) > 25
```

Comment: each record in membre table is connected with location table by no_membre column thus you GROUP it to use the aggregate COUNT() function. `HAVING COUNT(no_location) > 25` will filter the result set to only meeting this condition (more than 25 locations)

Comment: if this answered your question, you may check this as the correct answer to your problem.

Comment: i need help with the following query.

I have a table M wich contains membre_number, first_name, Last_name, Date_birth i need to know how meny members are older than the average of all the members first_name is paul. please note that many members are named paul.